# Sql Server Client protocols

Tags: sql-server-2005, network-protocols

What is VIA protocol in SQL Server Client Protocols?

more precisely what does VIA stands for?

Is it for chip-maker VIA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From following [SQL Data Access Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/3ef32b96-ecd7-40d9-95fd-dc6d4bccef45/#) thread on MSDN Forum:

***Virtual Interface Adapter (VIA) - A protocol that works with VIA hardware. This is a
specialized protocol; configuration details are available from your hardware vendor.***

There is a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Interface_Adapter) entry about it but it is also only a stub.

Answer (score 2):

From 
[Beginning SQL Server 2005 Administration](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=TVVLWLJtpIUC&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=via+protocol+sql+server&source=bl&ots=x62NmzAs1C&sig=N0KsRpIUQ4HH5MxWgcr5LPuwG20&hl=en&ei=viOuScKPPIG86gOEhYzgBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=7&ct=result) on Google Books:

> The VIA protocol is used to support VIA devices such as VIA Storage Area Network devices.